# startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_ALBUM) returns 0 on 'onResultActivity' method

Tags: android, node.js

I am trying to implement an activity which crops picture after selecting a picture in the gallery. I implemented camera one which takes a photo and then it shows crop screen and I can save the result. It displays it without any problem. But when I try to choose a picture in the gallery. It says 'Can't load'. 'onResultActivity()' gets resultCode: 0. I don't know why.

the main part of my code is this:

```js
    private void getImageFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(profileIconFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
    }

    private void getImageFromAlbum() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType(MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_ALBUM);
    }

    private Intent getCropIntent(Uri inputUri, Uri outputUri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "START getCropIntent() = inputUri : " + inputUri + " | outputUri : " + outputUri);

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        intent.setDataAndType(inputUri, "image/*");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);
        intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.toString());

        Log.d(TAG, "END getCropIntent() = intent : " + intent);

        return intent;
    }

    private void cropImageFromCamera() {
        Log.d(TAG, "START cropImageFromCamera()");

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(profileIconFile);
        Intent intent = getCropIntent(uri, uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);

        Log.d(TAG, "END cropImageFromCamera()");
    }

    private void cropImageFromAlbum(Uri inputUri) {
        Log.d(TAG, "START cropImageFromAlbum()");

        Uri outputUri = Uri.fromFile(profileIconFile);

        MyLog.d(TAG, "cropImageFromAlbum() = inputUri : " + inputUri + " | outputUri : " + outputUri);

        Intent intent = getCropIntent(inputUri, outputUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_ALBUM);

        Log.d(TAG, "END cropImageFromAlbum()");
    }

    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = requestCode : " + requestCode + " | resultCode : " + resultCode + " | intent : " + intent);

        switch (resultCode){
            case RESULT_FIRST_USER:
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = resultCode : 1, OK(FIRST USER)");
                break;
            case RESULT_OK:
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = resultCode : -1, OK");
                break;
            case RESULT_CANCELED:
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = resultCode : 0, CANCELED");
                break;
        }

        switch (requestCode){
            case PICK_FROM_CAMERA :
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = PICK_FROM_CAMERA");
                cropImageFromCamera();
                break;
            case PICK_FROM_ALBUM :
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = PICK_FROM_ALBUM > intent is " + intent);

                if(intent != null) {
                    Uri dataUri = intent.getData();

                    MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = PICK_FROM_ALBUM > dataUri is " + dataUri);

                    if (dataUri != null) {
                        cropImageFromAlbum(dataUri);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case CROP_FROM_CAMERA :
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = CROP_FROM_CAMERA > profileIconFile : " + profileIconFile + " | profileIconImage : " + profileIconImage );
                Picasso.with(this).load(profileIconFile).into(profileIconImage);
                uploadProfileIcon();
                break;
            case CROP_FROM_ALBUM :
                MyLog.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() = CROP_FROM_ALBUM > profileIconFile : " + profileIconFile + " | profileIconImage : " + profileIconImage );
                if(intent != null){
                    Picasso.with(this).load(profileIconFile).into(profileIconImage);
                    uploadProfileIcon();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void uploadProfileIcon() {
        Log.d(TAG, "START uploadProfileIcon() = memberInfoItem.seq : " + memberInfoItem.seq + " | profileIconFile : " + profileIconFile);

        RemoteLib.getInstance().uploadMemberIcon(memberInfoItem.seq, profileIconFile);

        memberInfoItem.memberIconFilename = profileIconFilename + ".png";

        Log.d(TAG, "END uploadProfileIcon() = memberInfoItem.seq : " + memberInfoItem.memberIconFilename);
    }
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There is no requirement for devices to have an activity that supports this undocumented and unsupported `Intent` action. There are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true)` this and check.

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
try {
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
    if (data != null) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap bitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

}